# Test middleware in Node.js mocking multipart/form-data

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, multipartform-data, middleware

So, I am searching for a solution on how to **unit test** middleware in **node.js**. Specifically on how to mock a multipart/form-data request. In nodejs I am using [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) to read the data on my backend. Here is an abstract of my code:

```js
// middleware.js
const multer = require('multer')
const storage = multer.memoryStorage()
const upload = multer({ storage }).single('data')

module.exports = (req, res) => 
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    upload(req, res, (err) => {
      err ? reject(err) : resolve({ message: 'No error on multer '})
    })
  }),
```

Then, on my controller:

```js
router.post('/myroute',
  (req, res, next) => {
    uploadFile(req, res)
      .then(() => { next() })
      .catch(res.json)
      .done()
  })
```

Now, to test this, I would require my middleware on my test file. I was working with [**node-mock-http**](https://github.com/howardabrams/node-mocks-http) but found out that they still don't have support for [multipart/form-data](https://github.com/howardabrams/node-mocks-http/issues/157)

Any idea how to test middleware in this circunstances? Thanks for the help!